# Subject and Verb Agreement: either/or, or neither/nor

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, coordinating-conjunctions

According to the rule "The verb in an or, either/or, or neither/nor sentence agrees with the noun or pronoun closest to it," is the sentence below correctly phrased? "I" is a singular subject but are is a plural verb.

> **She, my friends, and I are not going to the festival.**

?

Comment: *She, my friends and I* is considered one grammatical entity and so, because more than one person is being referenced, you use the plural form *are*. You are merely getting confused by the way this creates *I are* which is clearly wrong, just remember that you are grouping the list as one plural entity so you use the plural verb form.

Answer (score 1):

The rule you've cited actually doesn't apply to the example sentence, which happens to be correct.  In the case of your example, the plural verb is appropriate since the subject is plural--multiple subjects connected with *and*.

Comment: Could you expand your answer, at the moment it is a bit brief